# How would i find the string of a hash?

Tags: python, string, security, hash, passwords

This is the code(python) my teacher wrote. (with the prime numbers i've found using a bruteforce).
I also have some test data with passwords that have matching hashes (not that it really matters now that i've found the two primes used in the function).

Can anyone help me on the way of finding a way to "reverse" this or atleast give me a tip?

```
def prime_number_hash(s , 17299, 209569):
    """
    Will hash the string s using the two prime numbers p and n.
    """
    h = 0
    for k,l in enumerate(s):
        v = ord(l)
        # k is the index of the letter 
        h += v * pow(p,k)
    return h % n
```

Comment: Please show us some valid code.

Comment: If hashes were reversible they'd be a truly excellent compression. Think about the fact that even gigabytes or more end up with the same hash length as a single character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it. I just made 6 loops and tried every combination of the letter. And an exception to break out when i found it.
It was found within 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that you can't reconstruct the input string given its hash. The function has `209569` distinct output values, and there are many more possible input strings. See [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

If the task is to find *a* string that has the given hash, that is a different problem...

Comment: Yes the task is to find a string that has the hash 69731. Any tips? Do i have to bruteforce it?